# how somebody can generate fake IP addresses?

Tags: security, networking, web, ip

i have a problem with my website and that is someone make tremendous amount of fake comments and when i explore the comment details i realize that these comments generated from different locations around the world with different IP addresses . i assume that this cant done by peoples or different computers around the glob , i'm sure it's accomplished with a programming job . my question is not about how to prevent this , i'm asking HOW he/she generates fake IP addresses ?

Comment: Did you consider them using a [botnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet)? That would explain a lot. Also, you might read up about [IP spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing). As long as the actual server-response is not required by the attacker sending a message with a spoofed IP is not *that* hard. Quote wrom WikiPedia: `The machine that receives spoofed packets will send a response back to the forged source address, which means that this technique is mainly used when the attacker does not care about the response or the attacker has some way of guessing the response.`

Comment: i don't think it would be the botnet , or maybe . but i prefer to know is that possible with programming ?

Comment: There are lots of software and sites available that generate IP address and you can use it using that site or software.

Comment: `is that possible with programming ?`. Ofcourse it is, why not? All you need to do is modify packets being sent out. This would involve a "low level" approach using the TCP/IP stack etc. instead of using the (more usual) higher-level functions frameworks or programming languages usualy expose. But isn't something that can "only" be done by "elite hackers" (CSI style :P )

Comment: mind to introduce me one of that softwares ?

Comment: Not *intended* for "spoofing IP's", I think you should start out with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see for yourself how IP packets work etc. and then go from there. Wireshark is, AFAIK, one of the most user-friendly ways to play around with low-level packets.

Comment: the problem here shows up , i cant install wireshark on my server , it's just has the panel interface (Cpanel) , i know about the wireshark and packet header in all levels , but i cant .

Comment: Why not install Wireshark on your workstation then? Still looking for other software? [Pick one](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+forge+ip+address).

Comment: Oh, and also consider [Anonymous/Open proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy) and networks like [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)).

Comment: the workstation is outta my reach , and no any other software thanks dude , i think it's gonna take a broad amount of proxy servers , i'm still looking for programming approach :D

Comment: *"i'm still looking for programming approach"*. So?? Just "program" a [list of open proxies](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+open+proxies) into the "evil application" and use a new proxy for each "evil action"? There are thousands of these open proxies and lists are abundant. I don't see what this has to do with programming and, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15633947/215042) also, each method requires a different "programming" approach.

Answer (score 1):

To distill the answers out of [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633588/how-somebody-can-generate-fake-ip-addresses#comments-15633588) (in order of most likely case):

- "Anonymity networks" like [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_P2P).
- [Anonymous proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy)
- [Botnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet)
- [Forged/Spoofed IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing)

there are some more, usually a bit more "far fetched", options left out in this answer because these aren't likely used to spam comments.